# Creating a list of functions using a loop in R

Tags: r, loops, functional-programming

In [this introduction to functional programming](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html), the author Hadley Wickham creates the following function factory:

```
power <- function(exponent) {
  function(x) {
    x ^ exponent
 }
}
```

He then shows how this function can be used to define other functions, such as

```
square <- power(2)
cube <- power(3)
```

Now suppose I wanted to create these functions simultaneously via the following loop:

```
ftns <- lapply(2:3, power)
```

This doesn't seem to work, as 3 gets assigned to the exponent for all entries of the list:

```
as.list(environment(ftns[[1]]))

$exponent
[1] 3
```

Can someone please help me understand what's wrong with this code?

Thanks!

Comment: Your code works as expected for me: `as.list(environment(ftns[[1]]))` shows that the exponent is 2.

Comment: Can I ask if you are using an old version of R? - I can get your problem on an old R 2.15 I have on a memory stick here.

Comment: @thelatemail Hmm that is odd. I am using R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09).

Comment: @David - well, bgoldst below has the same version and same problem, so you're not crazy :-)

Comment: I can replicate this on 3.1.3 (Ubuntu) but not on 3.2.2 (Ubuntu) or 3.2.3 (Mac). Pretty fascinating.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're seeing is a consequence of R's use of *promises* to implement lazy argument evaluation. See [Promise objects](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Promise-objects).

The problem is that in the `power()` function the `exponent` argument is never evaluated, meaning the underlying promise is never called (at least not until the generated function is evaluated).

You can force the promise to be evaluated like this:

```
power <- function(exponent) { exponent; function(x) x^exponent; };
ftns <- lapply(2:3,power);
sapply(ftns,function(ftn) environment(ftn)$exponent);
## [1] 2 3
```

Without the `exponent;` statement to force evaluation of the promise, we see the issue:

```
power <- function(exponent) { function(x) x^exponent; };
ftns <- lapply(2:3,power);
sapply(ftns,function(ftn) environment(ftn)$exponent);
## [1] 3 3
```

---

Aha! The R [changelog](https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/NEWS) shows that this behavior was changed in 3.2.0:

> * Higher order functions such as the apply functions and Reduce()
>     now force arguments to the functions they apply in order to
>     eliminate undesirable interactions between lazy evaluation and
>     variable capture in closures.  This resolves PR#16093.

It's classified as a new feature.

Comment: Did you run OP's code? The issue cannot be reproduced.

Comment: @Heroka I'm not sure why others cannot reproduce the problem. Maybe it's an R version discrepancy? I have `R.version.string=='R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09)'`.